# How to create an Excel pivot table from a table (ListObject object) via PyWin32?

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, pywin32, excel-tables

I'm trying to automate Excel report generation in Python and I would really like to create a pivot table from a proper table, which equates to the ListObject object in COM. I used several code chunks I found in the web, and it goes like this:

```python
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
 
excel.Visible = True 
 
try:
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("\\".join((os.getcwd(), file)))
except com_error as e:
    if e.excepinfo[5] == -2146827284:
        print(("Filepath invalid: {filename}"))
    else:
        raise e
    sys.exit(1)
```

Now I need to create a proper table (ListObject), not merely a range, to ease future manual updates of the file:

```python
table_db_property = wb.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add()
table_db_property.Name = "SummaryTable"
table_db_property.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"


ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
ws.Name = "People Summary"
```

With that out of the way, now I would like to create the pivot table using this table as the source. But this is when the code crashes:

```python
PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=table_db_property.Range, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PivotTargetRange= wb.Worksheets("People Summary").Range("C5")
 
PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName="Test", DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)
```

The displayed error is the following (or a close variation of it):

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-4216b80db72c> in <module>
----> 1 PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName="Test", DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)
 
~\AppData\Local\Temp\42\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\PivotCache.py in CreatePivotTable(self, TableDestination, TableName, ReadData, DefaultVersion)
     42         # Result is of type PivotTable
     43         def CreatePivotTable(self, TableDestination=defaultNamedNotOptArg, TableName=defaultNamedOptArg, ReadData=defaultNamedOptArg, DefaultVersion=defaultNamedOptArg):
---> 44         ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1836, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),TableDestination
     45             , TableName, ReadData, DefaultVersion)
     46                 if ret is not None:
 
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I don't know how to debug this. I've tried switching the SourceData argument from the PivotCache function to table_db_property.Range() and tabla_db_property.DataBodyRange with no success.

Any hint to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are guesses, but try using the table name for `SourceData`:

```
SourceData='SummaryTable'
```

and an R1C1 reference for the `TableDestination`, including the sheet name:

```
TableDestination="'People Summary'!R5C3"
```

Comment: @MPadilla - glad to hear. The macro recorder in Excel ended up being helpful, just in case you run into similar issues in the future and need inspiration.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering again, but I tried the Macro recorder advice but couldn't create a slicer as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991420/create-slicer-object-in-excel-via-python

Any idea what is the variable Cache in that code?

Comment: I would assume a PivotCache.